# How to inspect a variable in XCODE?

Tags: iphone

Is there any command using which we can inspect a object in command line while app is running in DEBUG mode. I do not want to put description message in the code.

Comment: Do you want a command line command for the debug console?  Or is hovering with the mouse cursor in the Debugger GUI window at a breakpoint OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these resources. [one](http://www.meandmark.com/xcode3debugging.pdf) [two](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/000-Introduction/Introduction.html)

```
(gdb) p varName
```

Comment: Here it is printing the memory address of objects like dictionary, array etc. I want to see what is the data they are holding inside. Any clue on this?

Comment: Try `(gdb) p (float)[objName varFloat]`  I don't think you can use 'dot' syntax.  the other option is to do `(gdb) p (float)objName->_privateVar` but I don't think that'll work

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure. If you are debuging, breakpoints are automatically set to on. Just set a breakpoint to the line in which the variable is. The program stops as soon it reaches the line with the breakpoint. Just hold the cursor over the variable and all important data is displayed. I do it also that way all the time. ;-)